# Can't get RunTransaction with Firebase in Unity to work

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a game in Unity, using Firebase for user and game data.
Everything is fine saving the game to Unity, but in Multiplayer I have the challenge to pair an open game to a unique player 2.
The flow is:
1. You look for a game with a state of "open"
2. If no game is found within X seconds, a new one is created with the state of "open"

I have a query that returns open games (those with state "open")
**This query is added a Firebase eventhandler**

```
public void OnButtonLookForOpenMPGames()
{
this.OpenFirebaseGamesAsHost = this.LiveGamereference.OrderByChild("State").EqualTo(WYMSettings.MP_GAME_STATE_OPEN_TO_PLAYER2)
                .LimitToFirst(3);

this.OpenFirebaseGamesAsHost.ChildAdded += this.OnOpenMPGameFound;
}
```

**This fires fine in the handler:**

```
 private void OnOpenMPGameFound(object sender, ChildChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("Looking for open games");

        if (args.DatabaseError != null)
        {
            // handle errors
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Open game found (it may be my own)");

            // remove event listener because we got a hit
            // it will fire as many times as it's true!
            this.OpenFirebaseGamesAsHost.ChildAdded -= this.OnOpenMPGameFound;

            if (args.Snapshot.Child("HostId").Value.ToString() != FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.UserId)
            {
                Debug.Log("Other game than mine found open");

                // this.AddDelayedUpdateAction(() =>
                //      {
                //          this.MPGameLockInTransaction(args.Snapshot.Reference);
                //      });

                this.MPGameLockInTransaction(args.Snapshot.Reference);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem: The handler passes this on to the transaction function, but it fails with an inner exception (Internal Task Faulted) - I've tried many different variations, but can't figure this one out from the official Firebase example.

**Problem code:**
What I want to achieve is to lock only that game to those two players, the host and the players 2 in this example querying for open games. The State is an int, but here a string for clarity.

```
 private void MPGameLockInTransaction(DatabaseReference mpreference)
    {
        mpreference.RunTransaction(mutableData => 
        {

                MultiPlayerGame transactionMPG = mutableData.Value as MultiPlayerGame;

                if (transactionMPG == null)
                {
                    return TransactionResult.Abort();
                } 

                if (transactionMPG.State != "open")
                {
                    // game is taken, abort
                    Debug.Log("transaction aborted");
                    return TransactionResult.Abort();
                }


                transactionMPG.State = "game started";

                mutableData.Value = transactionMPG;

            return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);


        }).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Exception != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Transactionlock to game failed" + task.Exception.ToString());
                // Look over again
                // not implemented yet
           }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("starting game immediately");

                this.AddDelayedUpdateAction(() => this.StartMPGameImmediatelyFromSearch());

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the exception you get and point out in which line exactly?

Comment: This is the exception:
Transactionlock to game failedSystem.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.Database.DatabaseException: Internal task faulted ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.FirebaseException
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Firebase.Database.DatabaseException: Internal task faulted ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.FirebaseException

Comment: Happens at this line:
 Debug.Log("Transactionlock to game failed" + task.Exception.ToString());

Comment: Hm strange .. though this `Debug.Log("transaction aborted");` might already be a problem as well did you try to remove it? I'm no Firebase expert .. can you go through it line by line and check all values?

Comment: The mutable data is null the first time (as expected) then the error happens (and keeps firing, it's not the code crashes).
However, in the previous function the reference is correct, and reference is also correct in last function.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but it might be related to threading.

In newer .Net version `ContinueWith` might end on a thread where most of the Unity API may not be called (including `Debug.Log`).

Instead you could try and use [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) from the [extensions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) instead which was created exactly for this reason.

> With the .NET 4.x runtime, continuations may often execute in the background, whilst this extension method pushes them onto the **main thread**.
>
> The .NET 3.x runtime didn't have this issue as continuations were contained within the Parse library, which did this implicitly.